# BottomAppBar not loading properly

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, gradle

I'm trying to replicate [this BottomAppBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhwzL.png)

But no matter what guide I follow, the best I can get [is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VH4C.png)

I'm a complete newbie in Android development and this has been driving me crazy. I've checked created brand new projects to see if the issue was with mine. I painstakingly copied every single Gradle dependency that could be relevant from all the different guide, but nothing seems to work.

The editor's autocomplete recognizes the BottomAppBar view and its attributes, but it doesn't work at all in the preview, and just crashes in the app.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hlag.projecttabletop"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".activities.TestActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_drag_handle_black_24dp">
        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your styles.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your app theme should extend `MaterialComponents` theme, not the `AppCompatTheme`,

like this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

`BottomAppBar` should be wrapped in a `CoordinatorLayout`

and you are missing `app:fabAlignmentMode` for your bottom app bar

Comment: Happy coding... :-)

Comment: Just a note. `app:fabAlignmentMode` has the default value `FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_CENTER`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do it this way:

**style.xml** :

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

**activity_test.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_drag_handle_black_24dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_add_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Note :** Your parent layout should be `CoordinatorLayout`

This should work

Comment: If you use a MaterialTheme it is not necessary to set `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"` since it is the default style for the `BottomAppBar`